# Get the subsection using \eqref if the equation isnt't in the current subsection

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

As the title says, I want to define an `eqref` command such that if the equation is in the current subsection then it produces the usual (1) and that if the equation is in another subsection then the cite looks like ¶2.3 Equation (4). It is similar to my previous question [Include the subsection number in cross-reference to a theorem-like environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419191/include-the-subsection-number-in-cross-reference-to-a-theorem-like-environment) (the solution given by @egreg).

I have tried to copy the code with some changes. Here it is:

```
\let\eqref\relax
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\c@equation}{\perhapssubsection{\thesubsection}} 
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textsc{Equation}~\textup{(\ref{#1})}}
\makeatother
```

However, it does not work. Can you help me, please?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=\topsep,
spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\scshape,
bodyfont=\itshape,
notefont=\normalfont,
notebraces={}{.},
headpunct={},
postheadspace=1em,
headformat=\NAME\space\NUMBER.---\NOTE,
headindent=\parindent
%   qed=$\qedsymbol$%
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[style=theorem,name=Theorem,numberwithin=subsection]{theorem}


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{subsection}% Reset equation at \section
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\gobblesomething#1\csname thesection\endcsname{\begingroup\normalfont\S\thesection\endgroup}
\def\gobblesomethingother#1\csname thesubsection\endcsname{\begingroup\normalfont\P\thesubsection\endgroup}
\renewcommand*{\p@section}{\gobblesomething}
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\gobblesomethingother}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\def\gobblesomethinga#1\csname thetheorem\endcsname{\begingroup\normalfont\textsc{Theorem}~\thetheorem\endgroup}
\renewcommand*{\p@theorem}{\perhapssubsection{\thesubsection}\gobblesomethinga}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\perhapssubsection}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnF { #1 }{\thesubsection}{\P\textup{#1}~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{One}

\subsection{A}

\begin{theorem}
\label{th:E}
Bla bla bla
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\label{eq:E}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{B}

In \ref{th:E} and \eqref{eq:E}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\perhapssubsection` is not a default command, so you need to copy its definition also.

Comment: @Sigur Yes. The document is the same so it is already copied. Maybe I could add a MWE. I'm going to edit the question, thanks.

Comment: The definition of `\gobblethinga` is quite difficult to understand.

Comment: @egreg: Sure. It was thought to avoid italics when the reference is inside a theorem for example. And I cotomized it a bit, so probably  is very diffcult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do like this: a reference “Theorem 1.1.1” is *much* clearer than “¶1.1 Theorem 1”.

Anyway, some more juggling can do what you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\scshape,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  notefont=\normalfont,
  notebraces={}{.},
  headpunct={},
  postheadspace=1em,
  headformat=\NAME\space\NUMBER.---\NOTE,
  headindent=\parindent,
%   qed=$\qedsymbol$,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[style=theorem,name=Theorem,numberwithin=subsection]{theorem}


\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\perhapsbrackets{\arabic{equation}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@theorem}{\perhapssubsection{Theorem}{\thesubsection}}
\renewcommand*{\p@equation}{\perhapssubsection{Equation}{\thesubsection}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\eqref}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \bool_set_true:N \l_dog_brackets_bool
  \ref{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\bool_new:N \l_dog_brackets_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\perhapsbrackets}{m}
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_dog_brackets_bool { \textup{(#1)} } { \textup{#1} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\perhapssubsection}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeF { #2 }{\thesubsection}
   {
    \P\textup{#2}\nobreakspace
   }
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {Theorem}{\textsc{Theorem}\nobreakspace}
    {Equation}{\textsc{Equation}\nobreakspace}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{One}

\subsection{A}

\begin{theorem}
\label{th:E}
Bla bla bla
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\label{eq:E}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

In \ref{th:E} and \eqref{eq:E}

\subsection{B}

In \ref{th:E} and \eqref{eq:E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work on my computer. Frist of all I have to add the `chngcntr package` because the command `\counterwithin`. Now `LaTeX` says anoher error: literally                                                            Undefined control sequence.  \perhapssubsection code #1#2->\str_if_eq:eeF 
                                             {#2}{\thesubsection }{\P \textu...
                                              l.80 In \ref{th:E} and \eqref{eq:E}                                     I have just copied yuor code. It's really strange.

Comment: @Dog_69 You should first of all update your TeX system: `\counterwithin` has been part of LaTeX since April 1, 2018. But loading `chngcntr` can do as well in the meantime. The other problem is also due to an outdated distribution; you can change `\str_if_eq:eeF` to `\str_if_eq_x:nnF`.

Comment: Thanks. i'll do it in a minute. Anyway, I have found a (possibly) very very poor solution that makes what I want, so... But I'll edit my TeX

Comment: Indeed, it works fine.